# null object in onSaveInstanceState method

Tags: android

i'm trying to save object(saveMOvie) in onSaveinstanceState to restore it on screen rotated when debugging the code using tablet with main and detail fragments are next to each other  the value of object (saveMOvie) is null but when using mobile phone with only one fragment on screen the value of object (saveMOvie) doesn't equal null could anyone tell me why ??

MainActivityFragment

```
     public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
Movie moviesStore[];
GridView gridView;
String[] moviesImages;
View rootView;
ImageAdapter imgadpt;
boolean flag;
OnNewsItemSelectedListener onis;

Movie saveMOvie = new Movie();


public interface OnNewsItemSelectedListener {
    public void onMovieSelected(Movie movie);
}

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();//3shan myy7slash duplicate
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        onis = (OnNewsItemSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnNewsItemSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.open_settings_activity) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    //refresh used when there is no connection
    } else if (id == R.id.Refresh_activity) {
        onStart();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void updateMovies() {


    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String mode = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.key),
            getString(R.string.default_value));

    if (mode.equals("popular") || mode.equals("top_rated")) {
        new FetchMovies().execute(mode);
    } else {
        if (flag) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            FavouriteActivityFragment fav = new FavouriteActivityFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_main, fav);
            // fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FavouriteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    transaction.commit();
    flag = isTablet(getActivity());
    ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nf == null && nf.isConnected() != true) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(rootView, "Network Not Available", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("RECONNECT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        onStart();
                    }
                });

        snackbar.show();
    }
    updateMovies();
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("movie",saveMOvie);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {



        onis.onMovieSelected(saveMOvie);
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);


    return rootView;
}

public class FetchMovies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Movie[]> {
    private final String Log_Tag = FetchMovies.class.getSimpleName();

    private Movie[] getMovieDataFromJson(String moviesJasonStr)
            throws JSONException

    {


        final String lists = "results";
        final String decription = "overview";
        final String originalTitle = "original_title";
        final String moviePoster = "poster_path";
        final String userRating = "vote_average";
        final String releaseDate = "release_date";
        final String id = "id";
        JSONObject moviesJason = new JSONObject(moviesJasonStr);
        JSONArray moviesArray = moviesJason.getJSONArray(lists);


        // String[] resultStrs = new String[moviesArray.length()];
        moviesStore = new Movie[moviesArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject oneMovieInfo = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            moviesStore[i] = new Movie();

            moviesStore[i].setPlotSynopsis(oneMovieInfo.getString("overview"));
            moviesStore[i].setUserRating(oneMovieInfo.getString("vote_average"));
            moviesStore[i].setReleaseDate(oneMovieInfo.getString("release_date"));
            moviesStore[i].setOriginalTitle(oneMovieInfo.getString("original_title"));
            moviesStore[i].setMoviePoster(oneMovieInfo.getString("poster_path"));
            moviesStore[i].setId(oneMovieInfo.getString("id"));


        }


        return moviesStore;

    }

    @Override
    protected Movie[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String moviesJasonStr = null;
        StringBuilder baseUrl = new StringBuilder("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/");
        baseUrl.append(params[0]);
        baseUrl.append("?api_key=");
        baseUrl.append(BuildConfig.MOVIE_DP_API_KEY);

        try {

            // URL url = new URL("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=d51b32efc0520227b7c1c67e0f6417f6");
            URL url = new URL(baseUrl.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();


            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {

                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {

                return null;
            }
            moviesJasonStr = buffer.toString();
            Log.v(Log_Tag, "movies Jason String :" + moviesJasonStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Log_Tag, "Error ", e);
            //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"there is no internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(Log_Tag, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            return getMovieDataFromJson(moviesJasonStr);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(Log_Tag, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Movie[] result) {
        if (result != null) {

            moviesImages = new String[result.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                StringBuilder baseUrl = new StringBuilder();
                baseUrl.append("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/");
                baseUrl.append(result[i].getMoviePoster());

                moviesImages[i] = baseUrl.toString();
            }

            imgadpt = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), moviesImages);
            gridView.setAdapter(imgadpt);
          //   if(flag){
            // onis.onMovieSelected(moviesStore[0]);}
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    String posterUrl = (String) imgadpt.getItem(position);
                    saveMOvie = moviesStore[position];
                    if (flag) {
                        onis.onMovieSelected(moviesStore[position]);

                    } else {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);



                        intent.putExtra("movie", moviesStore[position]);


                        startActivity(intent);
                    }


                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot Fetch Data from api  check your internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }


}
```

}

Comment: value of saveMOvie is null where ?

Comment: in onSaveInstanceState method the saveMOvie is null only in tablet with two fragment next in each other

Comment: need code of onMovieSelected and why setRetainInstance is true

Answer (score 0):

When `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is called, check whether savedInstanceState is null, and if not, then getExtras from it (as it's a Bundle).

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) 
savedInstanceState.getParcelable(key)
```

Then do whatever you'd like with the object.